# Built in windows CLI in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line-interface, sublimetext

I've started to use Sublime Text again and I'd really like to have a package to load up Windows CLI in a tab so I can, say, create a new project for [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), or just browse through the directories.

Does a package like this exist? If not, how would I go about doing something like this?

Something like bash built into ST3 would be great, I really miss using ls.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Glue](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) a shot.  It's a cross-platform non-interactive interface to your shell that can be used inside Sublime Text.